# How can go back to a green underline in wsl this happen when code

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I go back  again to  a path or to a green underline this problem I encounter when I click code [. to o][1]pen a visual studio this problem occurs to my ubuntu terminal wsl

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXbbyK-scMQGwbT5mwEHgIBZE9Y8C3bw/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can press Ctrl+C to cancel all current operations and return to your shell.

Comment: It wont work it show like ^C  when I click this when I type code . it cannot show a green font with $ in wsl it just  like you are free typing in the terminal

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXbbyK-scMQGwbT5mwEHgIBZE9Y8C3bw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can try Ctrl+D, closing VS Code by hand or Ctrl+Z. You can also try starting VS Code by using `code . &` to run it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know that it will help (since I'm not quite sure exactly what is causing the problem), these would be my first two primary steps for troubleshooting VSCode/shell issues:

- *Try without shell customizations:*

  1. Exit your WSL2 instance.
  2. Start PowerShell
  3. Run `wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc` to start WSL without your shell startup files (which could be causing the problem).
  4. With WSL started, run `code .` again there.

  If it starts correctly and returns you to the shell prompt, then that points to a problem in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (or potentially other startup files).
- *Delete the VSCode/WSL server*

  1. From within WSL, `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/`
  2. Start `code .`

  The VSCode/WSL integration server will automatically be downloaded and reinstalled when starting `code`.